# Confusion about Logic between constructor and ngOnInit() in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, okta

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { OktaAuthService } from '@okta/okta-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  public title = 'my-project';
  public isAuthenticated: boolean;

  constructor(public oktaAuth: OktaAuthService) {
    this.oktaAuth.$authenticationState.subscribe(
      (isAuthenticated: boolean) => this.isAuthenticated = isAuthenticated
    );
  }

  async ngOnInit() {
    this.isAuthenticated = await this.oktaAuth.isAuthenticated();
  }

  login() {
    this.oktaAuth.loginRedirect();
  }

  logout() {
    this.oktaAuth.logout('/');
  }
}
```

I am new about Angular, when I saw this piece of code I am really confused. I read some article, I know constructors is to initialize a  class, ngOnInit is to run after constructor.
But in the code,

- What is the logic between the constructor and ngOnInit? For my
  understanding, in the constructor, it listen to the assignment
  function, and after construction, the class initilized by assigning
  the oktaAuth.isAuthenticated()
- when will the isAuthenticated varible be changed?
- why do we need async ngOnInit()?
- how can we do it if we want a sync way?

Comment: Just FYI, AngularJS implies that you're using the old Angular (version < 2). Angular 2+ is just called Angular.

Comment: @TomFaltesek Thank you for pointing it out

Comment: And making `ngOnInit()` async awai, loading of component rendering is stopping. And it's bad user experience. Constructor() is used to defining service DI in class, class is not fully loaded to Dom too. While ngOnInit() is called when class is fully loaded to Dom. So that we can assign default property values here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Async/await is just syntactic sugar for *thenables* (or Promises).

This uses asyc/await:

```
async ngOnInit() {
  this.isAuthenticated = await this.oktaAuth.isAuthenticated();
}
```

This does the same thing as above without the async/await keywords.

```
ngOnInit() {
  return this.oktaAuth.isAuthenticated().then(isAuth => this.isAuthenticated = isAuth);
}
```

Both of the above examples return a promise and, as @GaurangDhorda and @AluanHaddad pointed out, will likely delay the rendering of the component while waiting for the promise to resolve.

You can avoid this delay by not returning a promise from your `ngOnInit` method, like in this example:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.oktaAuth.isAuthenticated().then(isAuth => this.isAuthenticated = isAuth);
}
```

As for your questions about the constructor vs the `ngOnInit`, I would take a look at the docs for all of the [Angular lifecycle event hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks).

> **ngOnInit**
>
> Initialize the directive/component after Angular first displays the data-bound properties and sets the directive/component's input properties.
>
> Called once, after the first ngOnChanges().

Your `isAuthenticated` variable will be mutated when the `oktaAuth.isAuthenticated()` promise is resolved (in the `ngOnInit`) and whenever the `OktaAuthService` omits a new value through the `$authenticationState` observable (which you've subscribed to in the constructor).